# HTTP .get() method does not respond with anything

Tags: mongodb, http, axios, get, response

I am trying to use Express + MongoDB building React app.

I was able to post some documents to MongoDB and delete them. Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to get them using HTTP .get() method.

I have these routes:

```
router.post('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    const totalBalance = new TotalBalanceModelTemplate({
        totalBalance:request.body.totalBalance,
    });
    totalBalance.save()
    .then(data => {
        response.json(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.json(error);
    });
});

router.get('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Response ", response);
});
```

This is axios request:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Using get() method here");
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
    }, []);
```

However, it does not return anything (only 'Using get() method here' gets printed out to the console).

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you sending the response to the client? There's only `console.log` statement in the route handler function.

Comment: Have you added a route prefix in your app.js? If not, the route in your axios doesn't seem to exist - "/app/totalbalance". Try updating the route to "http://localhost:4000/totalbalance"

Comment: @KaranGaur yes, the route /app/totalbalance existed

Comment: @Yousaf, you were right, what I needed is to the client

Comment: I amended the route to: 

router.get('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {

    TotalBalanceModelTemplate.find((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return error
        } else {
            return response.json(data)
        }
    }) }